# How to get Webview's HTML content back on back button click?

Tags: android, webview

I am having a Webview with some HTML contains on it. If I click on any url link on that HTML based Webview I am navigated on that url. if there is again any url further I am able to nevigate to that url also. When I click on the back button I am able to get back also. But when I need to get back on the last Webview with HTML contains, it comes back with blank screen, My HTML contains on that Webview are not visiable or present. Can anyone tell me what should I include in my code to get those HTML contains back on Backbutton pressed in Webview.
I am using `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("baseurl", "html_string","text/html","UTF-8","");` to populate my Webview.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to use JSToJavainterface to get html data from JS to java

Comment: @Anuj But I want to show the HTML data only on the Webview when it returns back from the url on back button press.

Comment: Is this problem also there when you start with a real url?

Comment: @greenapps well I provide any url link to the URL history field of loadDataWithBaseURL it gives me that link and goes to that on back pressed. but when I pass null to that, it gives me bank page to my HTML based Webview page. ANy idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry that was not my question. You could have answered with yes or no.

Comment: well, I had used the public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) and opened the url of the webview on the devices browser. Now on back buton click it comes back to my HTML based Webview itself. Anyways @greenapps thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I used this WebViewClient Interface

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

It opens the url of my webview on the local browser of the Device. and when I press back button. it comes back on my HTML based Webpage. Hence no blank page is shown now on comming back on the webview from the URL of the webview.

Thanks to all how commented on this post.

Comment: How did you use this method, what value should it return.Please paste your code here for my help.

Comment: @BhawnaRaheja What you want really? and what error are you facing?

Comment: I am facing the same problem that you described above. My question is how you use this method to solve your problem. You must have used webclient interface and implement this method. But what had you returned from this method.

Comment: @BhawnaRaheja what you need, do you want that the Device's local browser should open the url link present in your webview or do you want that a the url should be opened in your App's webview?